# Symbolic Set Difference

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, intersection, sets

Suppose I have two symbolic set containing 2-points like

```
A={(m,n)| for m,n belonging to whole numbers}. So m,n=0,1,2,...
```

and I have another set containing 2-points like

```
B={(m,n+m)| for m,n belonging to whole numbers}
```

Now, how can someone use Mathematica to find the set difference A-B symbolically?

The answer will be something like `A-B={(1+m,n)| for m,n belonging to whole numbers and n<m}`

I didn't put Mathematica code because I have no idea how to define a set symbolically in Mathematica.